# How to use IPC to pass data from ActiveX Object into a VB6 application - (Single instance application)?

Tags: c#, javascript, messaging, activexobject, inter-process-communicat

I have created an ActiveX dll (object). I am calling the object from JavaScript in the IE browser. The object has a method named "run" which launches a VB6 application and passes a parameter to it.
To create the ActiveX object I have referred to [this link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/writinganactivexcontrolincsharp.aspx).

I am calling this script on click of URL in browser. The problem is that onclick the URL a new application launches every time. Instead, I would like to use IPC (inter process communication) so that I can check via JavaScript if the application is already launched and pass the parameter to it using IPC (else launch and pass parameter to it). The VB6 app will then need to be programmed in such a way that it is capable of accepting parameters. Instead of IPC is there any other method for messaging?

Please can you guide me on this topic.. or provide with some reference articles/links/code samples

Comment: And what does it have to do with C#?

Comment: I am using C#.NET to create the assembly file. I want to create a functionality (COM DLL assembly) that would enable the browser to pass some data (via URL click, I will pick the get querystring value) to a .exe application. At the moment I am able to launch the .exe application, however I would like to know more about IPC so that I could pass some message to the exe application. Or any other messaging technique for that matter.. Again, I am using C#.NET thats why the C# tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:-
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx

It contains a program which passes txt file path to the application via command line and the application opens up and loads the file contents. Upon running the app via command line for 2nd time using another filename as parameter, the file contents are shown in the same instance of the application. Cool!

**However, this code is not VB6**